# Java service method only for test

Tags: java, service, interface

Is there a way to use a service method (a method that is implemented in the service layer (Interface) ) only in test classes?

in my service interface i have a method that i want to use it only in test class 
and prevent or show some warning to other developers that doesn't use it in their
managerImpl or other palace such as controller

Comment: I'm writing test class for our business services methods, in my test case i need to remove all users (just for test) and i don't want put this method to the service layer, so what should i do ?

Comment: Can i use @Deprecated or something like this?

i want some way to alert other developers to "Don't use it in production mode"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets be precise about wording:

If you are really talking about a method of an Java *interface*; then Java8 would allow you to provide a default implementation that could throw an exception for example; and then you have very specific classes that implement this interface and maybe override that one method for test purposes.

If you are talking about "interfaces" in general; such as "the list of methods of some class" ... then this kind of "base throws" and "children override" could work as well.

Of course, the first answer might be visibility itself. If we are **not** talking about a real interface; you could at least make the method package protected; then usage is restricted to the same package.

Another option would be to follow [ISP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) and **segregate** your interfaces. If there is something that should only be used for "testing"; then consider putting those things into some "TestSupportInterface"; or something alike.

But again; most of these ideas work "by convention"; by providing some sort of information that the user has to digest ... but that can't be enforced.

Finally: you could consider to change your production code. Very often you might not need such "special test getters". In other words: if your tests are working like "fetch state of X. do something with X. fetch state of X again and compare". Sometimes this can be changed to **behavior** based testing (you don't check what happens to X; but you check what X does to Y, Z, ...).

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no concept in Java to warn developers about using methods.

Rethink if you 'really' need such a method, or if you could change your design to not require such a back door. (e.g. utilize the power of dependency injection). From my experience this is always possible.

If you are still convinced that you want this method implement it in your test code (e.g. by subclassing), not in production code.

Comment: I'm writing test class for our business services methods, in my test case i need to remove all users (just for test) and i don't want put this method to the service layer, so what should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

It's generally better not to put anything in your production code "only for tests".

You could create a service dedicated to all users suppression and place it in your test classpath.
Depending on your implementation, this service might be a subclass of your production user service.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other good answers: If you really need a method to be called by a test case but not by production code, you can make this method `private`. So unless someone changes the visibility nobody will use this method. And in your test case you can call it via [`PrivateAccessor`](http://junit-addons.sourceforge.net/junitx/util/PrivateAccessor.html).

But be careful: This is mostly considered as code smell. For your IDE this is a private and unused method, so there will be a warning message. And someone else could remove this method because of this.